# How to append form to a div inside other div using jquery in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  
  $("#buttonGenerate").click(function(){
   for(i = 0; i < document.getElementById('inputNumber').value; i++){
    $(".enterDetails").append('<div>Div Goes Here</div>');
   }
  });
    });
</script>
```

```css
.container-fluid {
 padding-top: 20%;
 padding-bottom: 20%;
}
.bg-1 { 
  background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bg-2 { 
  background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
  color: #ffffff;
}
.page-scroll {
 text-align: center;
}
.btn {
border-radius: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
}


.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #999;
    background: #fff;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover i,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus i{
    color: #999;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle i.animated {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle:hover i.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -moz-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Exam</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Exam.css">
      <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>


<div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
  <h1>Create Exam</h1>
 <div class="page-scroll">
  <a href="#enterDetails" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center" id="enterDetails">
 <form class="form-inline" id="listOfSections" role="form">
  <label>Enter No. of Sections :  &nbsp;</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">?</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" placeholder="1, 2, 5 etc" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="buttonGenerate" class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button>
 </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here i have given code of the Java Script and Exam.css and The whole HTML file. All the css and js of the bootstrap and jQuery i haven't given. All i want to do is just displaying no. of divs that inserted from the text field after the Enter No. Sections filed Dynamically. It's adding and at the same instant it is Disappearing and displaying the default again and going to create Page. So please some body help to do it correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong selector, you are using the class selector where it should be the id selector.

Change `$(".enterDetails")` to `$("#enterDetails")`

To avoid errors, you might want to check if the entered value is a number.

```
$(function(){
  $("#buttonGenerate").click(function(e){
  $('#error').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = 0,
        n = $('#inputNumber').val();
    if( !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n) ) {
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        $("#enterDetails").append('<div>Div Goes Here</div>');
      }     
    }
    else {
        $(this).after('<div id="error">Wrong input</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

Full example:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#buttonGenerate").on('click', function(e){
  $('#error').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = 0,
        n = $('#inputNumber').val();
    if( !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n) ) {
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        $("#enterDetails").append('<div>Div Goes Here</div>');
      }     
    }
    else {
        $(this).after('<div id="error">Wrong input</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container-fluid {
 padding-top: 20%;
 padding-bottom: 20%;
}
.bg-1 { 
  background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bg-2 { 
  background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
  color: #ffffff;
}
.page-scroll {
 text-align: center;
}
.btn {
border-radius: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    color: #666;
}


.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #999;
    background: #fff;
}

.btn-circle.btn-dark :hover i,
.btn-circle.btn-dark :focus i{
    color: #999;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle i.animated {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.page-scroll .btn-circle:hover i.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -moz-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center" id="enterDetails">
 <form class="form-inline" id="listOfSections" role="form">
  <label>Enter No. of Sections :  &nbsp;</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">?</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" placeholder="1, 2, 5 etc" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="buttonGenerate" class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude...it really worked... Actually i haven't included the e.preventDefault(); Method...so i got the error. Thanks for your help...